# return value iterator of std::generate_n, what can you do with it?

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, std, return-value

Out of curiosity!

What can you do with the returning `iterator` of [`std::generate_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n)?

Return value
:

> *Iterator one past the last element assigned if `count > 0`, first otherwise.*

```
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    auto iterator = std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), 10, [&]() {return j++;});
    std::cout << "type: " << typeid(iterator).name() << '\n';
/*
    for (iterator = v.begin(); iterator< v.end(); iterator++){
        std::cout << *iterator << " " << endl;
    }
*/
    for(auto a : v)
        std::cout << a << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
type: St20back_insert_iteratorISt6vectorIiSaIiEEE
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

`iterator` shows a few member functions, but they are mostly operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you want to generate elements for the first half and then use a different generator for the second half, then you can simply write:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int j = 0;
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    auto iterator = std::generate_n(v.begin(), 5, [&]() {return j++;});
    
    std::generate_n(iterator,5,[&](){ return j;});
    
    
    for (auto i : v){
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

Without manually calculating the `iterator` that points to the element after the ones from the first call.

Output is:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5 5
```

In your example `iterator` is just an iterator one past the last element of the vector and brings no big advantage because it is the same as `v.end()`.

Answer (score 5):

It's an output iterator. You an use it like any output iterator. It is the same type that you pass as the first argument - even same value in case nothing is generated.

Back inserter isn't exactly ideal example for this because it doesn't really care about the position (fun fact: incrementing a back inserter does nothing). A more important use case is an iterator to an existing element in which case we care about which elements we are writing over.

An extended example, using two different generators for the same container:

```
auto generator1 = [&]() { return j++; };
auto generator2 = [&]() { return j--; };
auto it = v.begin();
it = std::generate_n(it, 5, generator1);
it = std::generate_n(it, 5, generator2);
```

Comment: nice pieces of code, but it was thinking if the "iterator" would give me reference or something to the newly added elements to the vector, not sure.

Comment: @NaturalDemon It doesn't. It gives you a place to output more elements.

Answer (score 3):

---

> *What can you do the returning `iterator` of `std::generate_n`?*

You can use it to insert elements into your container.

Given that `std::generate_n` returns a `std::back_insert_iterator`, as defined in [std::back_insert_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator):

> *std::back_insert_iterator is a LegacyOutputIterator that appends to a container for which it was constructed. The container's `push_back()` member function is called whenever the iterator (whether dereferenced or not) is assigned to. Incrementing the `std::back_insert_iterator` is a no-op.*

Effectively what your code is doing is appending 10 more `int`s to the `std::vector`. I would imagine `j` is initialized with `0`, if it's not, you may be invoking undefined behavior.

---

> *Return value:*
>
> > *Iterator one past the last element assigned if `count > 0`, first otherwise.*

It's always pointing to one past the last element where a new element should be inserted, if the container is empty, it will be pointing to the first element of the container, which, again, is where the new element should be inserted.

Example:

```
iterator = 25;
```

Will append `25` to the vector, your output will be:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 25
```

---

Comment: please extend my code and show some examples.
 i tried some things, but no succes.

Comment: @NaturalDemon, note that `j` is undeclared in your code.

Comment: @NaturalDemon, it's a back_insert_iterator, you are assigning it a 'normal' iterator in the comented code, does that even compile?

Comment: @anastaciu no the code in the comment does not compile, the output is probably not from that code

Comment: @anastaciu, the loop doesn't compile, that's what i figuring out, how to use the iterator returned from std::generate_n.

Comment: @NaturalDemon why do you write in the question that this is the code and that is the output when it isnt? Consider that we can only see what you post for us. WHen you have broken code it is always better to show that broken code together with the error message instead of some code that is fine

Comment: @idclev 463035818, the code as is, does compile fine, but the for loop doesn't work using the iterator returned from std::generate_n.

Comment: @NaturalDemon yes, but in the question you show some code and some output, but the output is not from that code, where does the output come from then? For broken code you should include the error message. But nevermind, I am not attacking you in any way, just trying to suggest how the next question could be more clear

Comment: @idclev 463035818, that's the output from those lines of code, i ommited "#include ..., int main(){}, that's it.

Comment: @NaturalDemon if the code you posted produces `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` as output then something really weird is going on ;)

Comment: @ idclev 463035818 hehe, sorry, i forgot the loop, i thoughed it was insignificant, will update now.